# How to make donate without sign up with paypal in php?

Tags: php, paypal

I implemented with paypal in php.

https://www.wikitechy.com/php/paypal-donate-button-in-php

but it is asking sign up in paypal if I click on donate.
I want to make this without sign up.
I think it is possible, and saw as following article.

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional

And current website is as following.

https://aids4poor.com/donate.php

if someone has experience, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Documentations says already *This feature is available to Premier and Business account holders only*

Comment: @Dlk I think that is in reference to who can use this feature on the receiving end though.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags - your question is not related to PHP, HTML, CSS, or MySQL after all. Additionally, show what you've tried so far and where you are stuck

Comment: @CBroe Yes! Receiver have to signup for a Premier or a Business account to activate that future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enable guest payments**

Buyers can check out without a PayPal account by using guest payments.

**[To receive guest checkout payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/guest-payments/#to-receive-guest-checkout-payments)**

1. Enable the PayPal Account Optional option in your account settings.

   The path to this option for US accounts is:
2. Profile > Selling Preferences > Website Payment Preferences > PayPal
   Account Optional

Select **yes**.

**Additional information**

For new buyers:

Buyers need to complete their payments first, and then decide whether to save their information in a PayPal account for future purchases or not.

*This feature is available to Premier and Business account holders only*

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional